# Ant Design v4. How to show the error message from custom validator in form

Tags: reactjs, antd

How to get the error message from the validator and show it in the form? I have 2 types of errors: "Please enter password" - if the field is empty and "Incorrect password" - when the password does not match. How to realize this?

````
export const LoginPage = ({ startLogin }) => (
  <div>
    <Form
      name="normal_login"
      initialValues={{ remember: true }}
      onFinish={startLogin}
      validateTrigger='onSubmit'
    >

///////////////////////////////////THE CORE PART////////////////////////////////////////


      <Form.Item
        name="password"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter password!' }, ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
          //WHY THE MESSAGE ABOVE IS NOT SHOWN AT ALL?
          validator(_, value) {
            axios.get('users.json').then(({ data }) => {
              if (condition) //do smth.
              else if (condition) {
                throw new Error("Incorrect password"); //<-- HOW TO SHOW THIS
              }
    });
}).catch(e => {console.log(e); return e}); 
          },
        }),]}
      >


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        <Input.Password
          className="input"
          iconRender={visible => (visible ? <EyeTwoTone /> : <EyeInvisibleOutlined />)}
          prefix={<LockOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
          Log in
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  </div>

  );```
````